# How to guess the pronunciation of some inconsistencies in English?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling, rules

I’m not a native English speaker, and I have a lot of problems when is comes to pronouncing words like *archive, archon, zealot, heal, health*.

Why is the *ch* sometime pronounced like a *k*?

Why is the *ea* sometime pronounced like a French *i* or *è*?

Are there rules to follow when it comes to pronouncing these words, or do we just need to know them?

### Edit

This question is not a duplicate — sorry if I was not clear. I was not looking for an history course; I wanted rules or tips to help myself when it comes to pronounce these words. @brick's comment was pertinent.

I found something in Wikipedia that might be interesting [English spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_spelling) for this question. But after looking at all these rules and exceptions, I understand why everyone fallback to the easy answer  that you just have to know how it is pronounced.

Comment: Look at *Soup*'s answer [link](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/pronunciation-phonetics/49197-pronunciation-ch.html)

Comment: English spelling was fixed at a time when the pronunciation was undergoing extensive change. Since that time many words have entered the language from outside sources with different orthographic practices. At bottom, yeah, ya just gotta know em.

Comment: The pronunciation is perfectly consistent. You meant to complain about spelling. And we have quite a few questions like that already. The gist is, yes, you have to learn all spelling by heart. No, there is no other way. That's what native speakers have to do, too. (And by way of a side note, the French spelling is terribly inconsistent, too. Which is, surprise surprise, where English got some of its spelling inconsistencies from.)

Comment: Having Germanic, Roman and French influences in that order on the language over history probably has its role in this.

Comment: @RegDwighт Why do you feel like I am complaining? Really? I'm just trying to understand something be better in english. Plus, I didn't ask about the french language (otherwise I'd go on the french stackexchange) so why are you telling me that french has terrible inconsistency TOO (funny because it condraticts the fact that you just said that english is perfectly consistent...)?

Comment: @RegDwighт French and English are different in one regard here. Although you cannot deterministically map the pronunciation of a French word back to its spelling, you can much more often go the other way around than you can in English.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc The interesting thing is that educated native speakers of English will almost always come up with the same pronunciation of a new or made-up word. So there are “rules”, but it takes a lifetime to internalize them, and it is far too hard to teach them.

Comment: Please forgive me, but I honestly do not see how this is ***not*** a duplicate. Could you please explain again how it is not such? Thanks.

Comment: @tchrist Because the other thread does not help me. I don't really know how to properly formulate my question and I'm sorry for that. But the "why" is more like a "how". I want to know "How to pronounciate" instead of "Why they are pronouciated like that".

Comment: I just edited my title if it can help.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc Fyi, pronounciate is not a word.  As for your question, I understand what you are trying to ask, but I just don't know that there is AN answer.  There are so many rules to different combinations of letters, not to mention regional differences as well as differences between AE and BE.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the information. If pronounciate is not a word, what is the correct formulation?

Comment: @tchrist "The interesting thing is that educated native speakers of English will almost always come up with the same pronunciation of a new or made-up word."  I have to completely disagree with that. Forte, neanderthal, cache, melee, meme come quickly to mind as words that people, even educated people, often pronounce wrong if they've only seen them and never heard them.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc The verb is just "pronounce" as in "How do you pronounce this word?" or "Why are they pronounced like that?"  The way you pronounce a word is its pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often, it helps to know the history or origin of a word. You wonder why "ch" is sometimes pronounced "k". This is often the case for words of Greek origin (archive, chronological). Sometimes it is pronounced like "sh". This is usually true of words originating from French (chamois, ricochet).

The "rules" of English spelling are fluid to say the least. Don't worry if you get it wrong, especially with words borrowed from other languages.